# RDS Oracle SE - Performance troubleshooting options

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, amazon-rds, aws

I have an RDS Oracle SE2 instance with Amazon RDS. Our team is looking forward to move couple of applications to RDS. But we’re looking for options that are available in RDS Oracle SE to perform Performance tuning and management.

As of now I’m aware I can use Statspack. With Statspack not being supported by Oracle now, I’m looking for other options compatible with AWS RDS. Will OUTLINES work with RDS for Plan management ?

Has anyone tried any other tools that could help? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to run an EC2 instance as a dev environment. Given that you don't have access to the file system on an RDS database and that you have standard edition, you can't turn on 10046 and 10053 events and use tkprof to read the files, you can't use active session history (ASH) and Automatic Workload Repository (AWR) since you need to have enterprise to use those reports and Oracle would know if you used any of those features in an audit situation.

Your best bet is to look for blocking locks in prod and use and EC2 instance to do load testing possibly using set events 10046 and 10053. There might be another tool that you can use in RDS. I don't know what that would be. You are limited in what you can do give that you are running standard edition on an RDS instance.

---

Comment: I am not sure that will provide the needed information as the hardware and performance of the system on EC2 and RDS will be different. Depending on the setup of the RDS something as simple as doubling the amount of storage space available can have a drastic impact on performance from having more iops available.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Statspack is still supported (even if no more documented in Oracle Database official documentation since Oracle 10G).

In Oracle 19 Statspack files are still delivered and you can find in spcreate.sql header:

```
Rem    MODIFIED   (MM/DD/YY)
Rem    kchou       01/12/17 - Bug# 25233027 - Set _oracle_script=FALSE at the
Rem                           end
Rem    zhefan      07/08/15 - bug 21393238: Add tests for standby statspack
Rem    krajaman    08/10/12 - bug#14407622 - Remove connect; Use CURRENT_SCHEMA
Rem    sankejai    04/11/11 - set _oracle_script in session after connect
Rem    cdialeri    02/16/00 - 1191805
Rem    cdialeri    12/06/99 - 1103031
Rem    cdialeri    08/13/99 - Created
```

You can also find recent My Oracle Support notes on Statspack such as:
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2020285_1.html

There is also one registered bug for Statspack on Oracle 19c linked to DBMS_JOB transition to DBMS_SCHEDULER with a documented workaround.